How can I both export execution plan XML and get column names in tables?
I need to get both the full text of an actual execution plan and my full table of results with column names from sqlcmd. My first requirement forces to me pass in -y 0 as documented here. However, this appears to disable column names appearing in my table's output. I cannot find any reference to this in the documentation. So how can I both pass in -y 0 and get column names?
Alternatives to sqlcmd are not an option. I'm using sqlcmd because, as far as I can tell, Emacs demands that I must and Emacs is the only IDE that I know of for Microsoft SQL Server on Linux. My version is

~$: sqlcmd -?
Microsoft (R) SQL Server Command Line Tool
Version 18.2.0001.1 Linux
Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.


Doesn't azure data studio support linux?

It does, and I use it daily on Linux, @siggemannen . It even has built in support for query plans. Not to mention there are other IDEs other than Emacs: DBeaver as another example (not that I recommend its use).

@ThomA perhaps OP actually wanted to get a list of linux interfaces but didn't want to be downvoted, and perhaps we fell into the trap

Honestly, this smells like an XY Problem to me, @siggemannen .

@siggemannen Or I just went to Emacs as my first solution, never checked for any more, and want to see if I can get it working as desired. ADS probably isn't a bad idea, but I'm deep in the Emacs hole at the moment.

Wouldn't it be very hard to actually understand the query plan in text mode? I like your style, but it seems you really like to make things difficult for yourself judging from your other questions :)

So because you've chosen to use Emacs you are now forced to use Emacs, and therefore your statement "Emacs is the only IDE that I know of for Microsoft SQL Server on Linux" is actually entirely unrelated? It's not that you're unaware of other IDEs it's that you don't want to use other IDEs (or are being told you aren't allowed to due to arbitrary reasons)?

https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/233200/276164 alludes that -y 0 removes the headers altogether, it might not be documented though

In sqlcmd it explicitly states that using the -h and -y options are mutually exclusive, @siggemannen : Sqlcmd: The -h and the -y 0 options are mutually exclusive. Oddly in sqlcmd-go it doesn't generate said error (it just doesn't return headers).

@ThomA I knew that ADS existed, but I don't know about its Linux support.

@siggemannen I have a third-party tool for reading execution plan XML.

"but I don't know about its Linux support." As I stated, it's supported on Linux (so now you do know). I've been running it on Linux since is was called "SQL Operations Studio" (and I wish it was still called that, dumping "Azure" at the start of the name was stupid Microsoft...). It's designed to be cross platform compatible. The only platform it doesn't support (yet) is ARM64 on Linux; not sure why there's no build for that (yet), as Windows and Apple both have such builds.

@ThomA Thanks. I'll give it a look. Does it still suck compared to SSMS? I hear that Kendra Little has been working very hard to improve it.

Why not give it a spin and see how you like it comparing to emacs? Most things are better than SSMS to be honest, it's only strength is in the functional support, not GUI style

It's come a long way in recent years. Kendra has been working hard to give it a lot of new features, some that won't be coming to SSMS as well. They're different tools, which people do seem to forget; that Microsoft badged ADS a "Linux replacement to SSMS" at first is part of why it was so poorly received initially as it just wasn't. I admit, there are features of SSMS that I wish ADS had, but there actually are some ADS features that I wish SSMS supported at times too. It's "swings and roundabouts". I've  happily been use both, and enjoying the experience, for a couple years now.

But we are disgressing from on-topicness for [so]. It could be a good Discussion though.

Don't know if there are any docs about this, but I recently had the pleasure of reading through sqlcmd-go source code, where we can see how the headers are printed:
https://github.com/microsoft/go-sqlcmd/blob/main/pkg/sqlcmd/format.go#L150
if f.vars.RowsBetweenHeaders() > -1 && f.format == "horizontal" && !f.xml {
        f.printColumnHeadings()
    }

Looking up RowsBetweenHeaders definition it says:
https://github.com/microsoft/go-sqlcmd/blob/main/pkg/sqlcmd/variables.go#L164
// RowsBetweenHeaders is the value of SQLCMDHEADERS variable.
// When MaxVarColumnWidth() is 0, it returns -1
func (v Variables) RowsBetweenHeaders() int64 {
    if v.MaxVarColumnWidth() == 0 {
        return -1
    }
    h := mustValue(v[SQLCMDHEADERS])
    return h
}

So it would seem that these two settings are in antithesis with each other.
You might have some luck adding an issue or a pull request to add another option which prints the headers anyway, something like: --always-print-long-values-as-if-max-width-is-0-but-headers-are-still-ok-to-print. I might even upvote that

That's the Go version. Are you sure it's applicable?

It's supposed to be a functional equivalent, and i don't have the "real" version's code at hand

Nor will you be able to, @siggemannen . The non-Go version isn't open source.
